# window.applicationCache.status always 0 in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, application-cache

I have a website with a manifest that validates (http://manifest-validator.com/), and files are clearly downloaded since the "progress" event is fired for each file - but, window.applicationCache.status is always 0 (which mean the website does not have a cache manifest). This is in Firefox 11.

This is at first load. When i refresh the page after the manifest is donwloaded, the applicationcache status if first checking, and the idle - which is correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing similar results — Firefox still has major issues with applicationCache status and eventing.

I've filed [bug 825618](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=825618) to hopefully get this a little bit more attention again, although I'm seeing a few [other](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=730424) similar [bugs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=432055) that should have flagged the problem a long time ago but are still basically unresolved.